# Google's Places API and JQuery request - Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, google-places-api

I doing some testing for a project I got in mind which involves using places nearby. So I went with the big guy and started messing around with Google's Places Api. I'm using leaflet with openstreet tiles for my map. Now everything is fine until I try to use the dang thing.

```
var lat = coords.lat;
var lng = coords.lng;
var apiUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json";
var data = {
    key: 'AIzaSyBl8bmE8kQT7RjoXhP6k2yDti44h9-fSUI',
    location: lat+','+lng,
    radius: '10000',
    sensor: 'false',
    rankby: 'prominence',
    types: 'bar|night_club'
};
$.ajax({
  url: apiUrl,
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,    
  dataType:"jsonp",
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                // console.log(data.next_page_token);
          }
});
```

Changing the `dataType` property to `json` I get `Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` Using jsonp I get a parsing error `Unexpected token :` Obviusly `$.parseJSON` does not work... Is there a way to make this work without having to use Google Maps Api? If the answer is no... Is there another places api as good as google's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're trying to use the [Places API web service](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search), which is meant for use from server code and does not support the JSONP output you'd need for JavaScript.

In JavaScript, you need to use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) from the [Maps API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). You can't just hit a URL directly from JavaScript or jQuery code. (You *could* probably discover the URL pattern that the Places Library uses, but the terms of service don't allow direct use without going through the API/Library, and the URL could change at any time.)

Is there a reason you don't want to use the Maps API from JavaScript?

Comment: Honestly, I want to make an app/service from my work and want to stay away from google as much as I can.

Comment: That's reasonable enough, of course. What I was puzzled about was the idea of wanting to use the Places API web service directly from JavaScript without going through the Maps API to use it. You'd still be using Google services either way.

Comment: Yeah I made my peace and started using the maps api.

Comment: I know its an old topic, but with the trend of FE frameworks like angular, its easier to integrate the simple REST service. I was trying to use angular-resource but was seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/joshtronic/php-googleplaces

Just made this and uploaded it to one of my websites.

```
<?php
include 'GooglePlaces.php';
include 'GooglePlacesClient.php';
$google_places = new joshtronic\GooglePlaces('your_key');
$google_places->location = array(<your_lat>, <your_lon>);
$google_places->radius   = 800;
$results                 = $google_places->nearbySearch();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
echo json_encode($results);
```