# Not getting any nearby restaurant using Google place API

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

i am trying to get a list of all restaurants near user Location. For some co-ordinates i am getting results but for some location i am getting nothing. For example:

Getting no results for this: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=77.04744149999999,28.5080526&radius=50000&type=restaurant=&key=%20AIzaSyBwJsemNhTY8_HZDc3wAfhUrY0xrLm6EWY

Note : Above coordinates are for Gurgaon sector 23 A Loaction

Getting Results for this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.6639,-83.5552&radius=50000&type=restaurant=&key=%20AIzaSyBwJsemNhTY8_HZDc3wAfhUrY0xrLm6EWY

can anyone tell me what is wrong going on here with me.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of **two main reasons**:

*1. The coordinates you are using are invalid.*

OR

*2. There are simply no restaurants nearby that are registered in the Google Place database.*

Other than that I don't see any mistakes in the way you are using the API (I get the same result, by the way).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now i am stuck with CORS issue. Below is my Code:  '$.ajax( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&namecruise=&key=%20AIzaSyBwJsemNhTY8_HZDc3wAfhUrY0xrLm6EWY" )
  .done(function(response) {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function(response) {
    alert( "error" );
  })'   **Error:**  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.  **How can i hit Google place API without getting CORS issue????**

Comment: I am guessing you are testing your script locally (from a file on your PC and not from a server)? If so you need to simulate a web server (so you get the behavior of a web server). Easiest is to use the Chrome app 'Web Server for Chrome': https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en
If that doesn't work can you refer to the question below and look into using the library instead of a direct URL for your Place requests?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847623/googles-places-api-and-jquery-request-origin-http-localhost-is-not-allowed