# How can do you make an API call without a proxy server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, create-react-app

I have a URL for a  Google Places API that returns the proper JSON, but when I use fetch, I get this error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here's my code:

```
fetch(url, {
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log('data', data))
.catch(e => console.log('e', e))
```

The reason why I don't want to make a proxy server is that I'm using a static site hosting service (and it's just more work to make a proxy server). I figured that if I already have a working URL, it should be pretty simple to just fetch the JSON from that URL. This is for a React app (made with create-react-app).

Comment: Your server needs to support `CORS`. Just enable it.

Comment: "without a proxy server"

Comment: What does CORS have to do with "proxy"? The server either allows cross site resource sharing or not.

Comment: It'd be helpful if code was provided.  How do I enable CORS on the Google Places API? Or on my local server? or the static hosting service?  What server are you referring to?  I don't know how to "just enable it"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15847722

Comment: I thought you're doing this on your server and then calling your own server from browser. If you're calling Google Api directly from browser, you need to use their own library instead of `fetch`.